# Google Apps Script error mistaking variable for a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making an Elo rating leaderboard system in Google Sheets using Apps Script and while executing the following function which calculates the Elo changes I get the error "TypeError: kleft is not a function" I do not understand why my variable "kleft" is being mistaken for a function or where I am going wrong since I've written a similar code multiple times before without any issues.

```
//function to calculate Elo change
function elorat(leftscore,rightscore){ //leftscore and rightscore are the actual points scored by the two players in the match
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mtd = sheet.getSheetByName('MTD');
  var leftelo = mtd.getRange("K4").getValue(); //elo of player 1 before the game
  var rightelo = mtd.getRange("N4").getValue(); //elo of player 2 before the game
  var expectleft = 1/(1 + Math.pow(10,(rightelo-leftelo)/1000)); //expected points scored by player1 
  var expectright = 1/(1 + Math.pow(10,(leftelo-rightelo)/1000)); //expected points scored by player2
  var kleft = 0; //declaring the k-factor to be used in calculations
  var kright = 0;
  if(1000<leftelo<9000){
    var kleft = Math.round((-0.00001125*(leftelo-1000)*(leftelo-9000))+20); //adjusting k-factor of player1 based on current elo
  }
  else{
    var kleft = 20; //boundary case
  }
  if(1000<rightelo<9000){
    var kright = Math.round((-0.00001125*(rightelo-1000)*(rightelo-9000))+20);
  }
  else{
    var kright = 20;
  }
  var leftchange = Math.round(kleft(leftscore-expectleft)); //amount of change in elo post match for player1
  var rightchange = Math.round(kright(rightscore-expectright)); //amount of change in elo post match for player2
  mtd.getRange("K5").setValue(leftchange); //setting values onto the sheet
  mtd.getRange("N5").setValue(rightchange); 
  mtd.getRange("K6").setValue(leftelo+leftchange); 
  mtd.getRange("N6").setValue(rightelo+rightchange);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

**Issue 1:**

First of all, this expression `if(1000<leftelo<9000)` evaluates always to `true`.

You can test it yourself if you `console.log(1000<5<9000)` you will still get `true`.

Replace it with:

```
if(leftelo > 1000 && leftelo < 9000)
```

and the same for `rightelo`

**Issue 2:**

Both `kleft` and `kright` are normal variables but you use them indeed as functions and this is why the compiler gives that error.

In almost all of the programming languages this expression `kleft(leftscore-expectleft)` means that you have a function with the name `kleft` and you are trying to pass a value that is the result of `leftscore-expectleft`.

What you want instead is to **multiply** `kleft` with `(leftscore-expectleft)`:

```
kleft * (leftscore-expectleft)
kright * (rightscore-expectright)
```

Finally, I am not sure where you are calling the `elorat` function. If this is all your code, then again, this won't work because this function is expecting two arguments. But since you didn't get an error for that, I assume there is some code that is not shared here.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, worked as intended and I'll try to keep both these things in mind in the future.